# How to check if an object in an empty state?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, states, animator

How to check if an object with animator is currently in an empty state?

I need to disable the object using SetActive(false), so that:

- if the object is in transition between states - finish the transition and then disable it.
- if the object is in default empty state - disable it immediately.

This code works if the object is in transition, but doesn't work if it is in empty state:

```
MyObject.GetComponent<Animator>().IsInTransition(0)
```

Comment: Test for null and make sure you do not set object to a value until it finishes each state.  If you are running Async then put object in Lock state while transitions between states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok here's how I did it.**

I'm assuming you know the name of your "default empty state" that you want to disable your object in.

Declare a static int variable which has the "default empty state" as a string to hash like this:

```
 static int VAR-NAME = Animator.StringToHash("Base.NAMEOFSTATE");
```

This is assuming that your base layer is called "Base".

Then in Update(), put the current state in a variable like this:

```
currentState = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
```

and then use an If statement to check if your "default empty state" is equal to the current state like this:

```
if (currentState.nameHash == VAR-NAME){
      Debug.Log("Do Stuff Here");
 }
```

**Have fun coding!**